# Typoscript wrap a wrapper

Tags: translation, typoscript, typolink

I'm fairly new to typoscript and the manual (which I tried to read) isn't that helpful.

I have the following typoscript:

```
30 = TEXT
  30 {
    typolink {
      parameter = 1079
      returnLast = url
    }
    wrap (
            <li class="mod-metanav--item">
             <a class="mod-metanav--link" href="|">
              Help
             </a>
            </li>
    )

  }
```

Now, the word «Help» needs to be translated.

I found out that I can use something like this to translate text in TS

```
5 = TEXT
5.data = LLL:fileadmin/content/translation.xml:help
5.wrap(
<li class="mod-metanav--item">
  <span style="font-size: 10px; color: #777;">|</span>
</li>
)
```

But, I need to kind of double-wrap the text (5) into the link (30) and that's where I fail.

I found some documentation on wrap2/wrap3 and innerWrap/outerWrap, but there aren't any examples that match my case and I can't adapt the examples I find to my case...

The first part (30) was made by someone else and I have the suspicion that there's another way to achieve this...

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all who run into the same problem - here's what I came up with:

```
30 = TEXT
  30 {
    typolink {
      parameter = 1079
      returnLast = url
    }
    wrap (
             <a class="mod-metanav--link" href="|">

    )

    prepend = COA
    prepend{
      10 = TEXT
      10.value = <li class="mod-metanav--item">
    }

    append = COA
        append{
            10 = TEXT
            10.data = LLL:fileadmin/content/translation.txt:hilfe
            10.wrap(
                |
                </a>
                </li>
            )
        }
  }
```

The trick is to pre-/append the additional parts.

Still it feels like an ugly hack and I'm sure I'm supposed to put the HTML-part into the template.